# Spring data named query select entity where two columns are equal

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data

I would like to select all `Authority`s where `Authority.id` and `Authority.top` are equal. While the following could not produce the desired outcome, how to implement it using a named query but not a native one?

```
@Query("SELECT Authority WHERE Authority.id = Authority.top")  // how?
List<Authority> findTop();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

1) Without an alias:

```
@Query("FROM Authority WHERE id = top")  
List<Authority> findTop();
```

2) With an alias:

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM Authority a WHERE a.id = a.top") 
List<Authority> findTop();
```

In your case option one is preferrable of course

Answer (score 0):

I think the query is syntactically wrong.

It has to be,

`SELECT * FROM Authority WHERE Authority.id = Authority.top`

OR you can query the columns of your interest like this,

`SELECT Authority.id, Authority.name FROM Authority WHERE Authority.id = Authority.top`